# Integration of the Mongodb Atlas with Grafana

Tags: mongodb, grafana, prometheus, telegraf, mongodb-atlas

My `Mongo` Clusters are hosted at the `mongodb` `Atlas` the Saas of it. Even though he has his own monitoring, I want to concentrate everything in `Grafana`.

I did not find any connection plugin of `grafana` with `Atlas`, I even created a custom but I could not connect to the `atlas`, even configuring his whitelist and `apikey`.

I want to know if anyone has already done this integration.

My next step is to perform through `Prometheus` or use `Telegraf`.

Answer (score 3):

If it helps here's how I got it working with Atlas. You definitely need '[inputs.mongodb.ssl]' enabled = true for Atlas.

```
[[inputs.mongodb]]
  servers = ["mongodb://username:password@xxx-yyy-shard-00-00-zzzz.mongodb.net:27017","mongodb://username:password@xxx-yyy-shard-00-01-zzzz.mongodb.net:27017","mongodb://username:password@xxx-yyy-shard-00-02-zzzz.mongodb.net:27017"]
  gather_perdb_stats = true
  [inputs.mongodb.ssl]
    enabled = true
  [inputs.mongodb.tags]
    cluster = "mycluster"
```